# R minus in row name makes name sometimes unaccessible

Tags: r, string, format

I have an error I cant recreate with smaller examples so I hope anyone has an idea where to look at.

## The problem

As described in the code-comments: rownamesX is not found in the rownames of the matrix (But they are there of course). If I print the not-found names, something like this comes out:

- hsaâˆ’miRâˆ’00

It should be

- hsa-miR-00

Further, the I tested some different approaches:

- Code works if I source the subscript directly in Rstudio in the console (ctrl-shift-s hotkey)
- Code works if I call the function in the Console (Ctrl-Enter on the line)
- Code does not work if the subscript is sourced in the main script by (Ctrl-Enter on the line)
- Code does not work if the whole main.R is sourced (ctrl-shift-s hotkey)

## My environment:

1. The data matrix

   - ~200k elements
   - rownames in the form of "type-type2-number"
   - colnames (=samples) : "S1", "S2", ...
2. The call:

   - A main script

     - sources a subscript

       - sources a function
       - calls the function with the data matrix as parameter
3. The function:

   ```
   myFunction <- function(rownamesX = c("type-type2-number")
                          ,mat){
       indexes <- which(rownames(mat) %in% rownamesX) # This is empty
       mat.part <- mat[indexes, ] # therefore his is empty
       resp <- mat.part[1, ] - mat.part[2, ] # therefore this yields an error 
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was just an minimal working example and I did not think of the matrix-naming that second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was quite easy:
There are more than one "-":

−

-

These two look even more equal in Rstudio than here. So I looked for the first(larger) one when the second (smaller) one was in the rowname